# Do I need to copy a block if I use it in the method it was passsed to?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have a method similar to this:

```
- (void)loadStoreWithCompletion:(CompletionBlock)loadCompletion
{
    dispatch_queue_t loadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("loadQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    dispatch_async(loadQueue, ^{

        // ... Do background stuff ...
    });

    dispatch_async(loadQueue, ^{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            loadCompletion();
        });
    });

    dispatch_release(loadQueue);
}
```

Do I need to copy the `loadCompletion` block because it only might get called when the caller of this method no longer exists, or is it fine like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rely on `dispatch_async()` doing the right thing with the blocks that are passed to it directly.  It's also the case that when a block is copied, it copies any blocks which are captured by it.  Since `loadCompletion` is referenced by the inner block and it is not declared with `__block`, it is captured.  In other words, you're fine.

Answer (score 3):

The act of referencing the block parameter inside another block will cause it to be copied to the heap implicitly, so you don't need to explicitly do so.

Comment: only if that block is copied

Comment: Sure. The point here is that it will be handled automatically if it needs to be handled at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine like this. But you should make 1 change in your code:

```
dispatch_async(loadQueue, ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (loadCompletion) {
            loadCompletion();       
        }
    });
});
```

You can test it yourself. If you call the method without any parameters (`[instance loadStoreWithCompletion:nil];`), in your version of the code the app would crash upon invoking the completion handler. The block check will prevent any crashes in case the block does not exist (anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Blocks are allocated on the stack by the caller, this means that once out of scope, an invocation leads to an error.

You should always copy them to the heap when you intend to use them later (as in a callback which happens asynchronously), you can do it either

- by directly invoking `[block copy]`
- by storing them in a property which is declared as `copy`

Mind that retaining them or releasing them doesn't always work because they might be on stack.

Comment: "You should always copy them to the heap" No, only if your function is storing it somewhere that will outlive the call.

Comment: @newacct: I've been more specific, usually blocks are used asynchronously, that's why most of the cases you need to copy them. I guess that if they don't oulive the call then you wouldn't need a block at all.

Comment: But if you pass it to a function, and that function stores the block for later use and does asynchronous stuff with it, it's that function's responsibility to copy it if necessary. You do not need to know (and should not care) what a called function does to do the right thing. The OP's function does not store the block in an instance variable or something anywhere in the body of the function. Hence, he does not need to copy it. What happens in his function is all that matters.